# How to access single field in views-view-fields.html.twig

Tags: views, theming

If I enumerate all fields using loop then everything is printed properly:

```
{% for field in fields -%}
    {{ field.content }}
{%- endfor %}
```

But I need to print here the fields individually and the following prints nothing:

```
{{ fields[0].content }}
```

What's wrong? This is used in `views-view-fields.html.twig`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve it with:

```
{{ fields.machine_name_of_field.content }}
```

So for example if your field is a title with:

```
{{ fields.title.content }}
```

Install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to list key / values inside the array of fields with:

```
{{ dsm(fields) }}
```

Comment: Individual comments work great. Thanks. {{ dsm(fields) }} prints nothing. Devel module is installed. I need to print image url and all hints are failing thus the dump method would be helpful. I've tried: {{ fields.field_image.entity.fileuri }} and {{ file_url(fields.field_image.0.entity.uri.value) }} and many others. Needless to say that {{ fields.field_image.content }} prints the <img> perfectly. However I need to surpress the width/height attributes.